# Código complexo interfere no desempenho da aplicação?

Tags: c#, asp.net, desempenho

Tenho uma aplicação web em C# um tanto legada, que funciona em meu cliente, mas já faz cerca de 3 anos.

Na época, programei como aprendi na faculdade e não conhecia o conceito de código limpo. Ela não é tão grande, porem levando em questão de complexidade, acredito que seja ainda bem complexa, comparando aos códigos que escrevo hoje. E notei que esta aplicação muitas vezes ocupa grande espaço da memoria ram do meu servidor, variando entre 240mb, e 700mb. Acreditando que aplicações do mesmo porte, talvez não ocuparia mais de 128mb.

Gostaria de saber se possíveis complexidades no meu código, como um loop dentro de outro, if's dentro de outros if's, e coisas assim, podem ser responsáveis pelo desempenho da minha aplicação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Complexidade

Ao contrário do que alguém pode pensar a princípio, um bom programa geralmente será menos complexo do que um programa ruim. Muitas pessoas acham que o melhor programador é quem escreve o código mais difícil e contra-intuitivo.

Na verdade, o bom programador é o que resolve problemas complexas da forma mais simples possível. Isso ocorre porque quando o desenvolvedor é mais experiente, ele aprende a resolver o problema diretamente, sem dar "voltas" desnecessárias.

Outro fator de maturidade de um desenvolvedor é a questão de primeiro resolver o problema, depois implementar a solução. Os mais novos geralmente saem programando sem saber muito bem onde vão chegar. O código acaba até "funcionando", mas com gambiarras e partes completamente desnecessárias.

> Sugestão de leitura: [Bons programadores escrevem código complexo?](http://luizricardo.org/2013/07/bons-programadores-escrevem-codigo-complexo/)

Lógico que alguns algoritmos são inerentemente complexos, mas a verdade é que em geral nunca chegamos a uma solução ótima

Existe toda uma teoria sobre a complexidade de algoritmos, mas o que em geral afeta mesmo o a complexidade é a quantidade de loops e comparações realizadas.

## Memória vs. Desempenho

Memória e desempenho geralmente não são proporcionais.

Um bom programa pode usar mais memória para *cache* e otimizações finas, uma estrutura mais elaborada de classes e mais. Um programa ruim pode fazer todas as operações em disco ou diretamente em banco de dados e conter menos classes, porém sem separação de responsabilidades.

Por isso, creio ser melhor analisar esses itens em separado...

### Memória

A não ser nos casos em que citei, onde propositalmente usamos mais memória, um programa bem feito vai ocupar menos memória quando o desenvolvedor usa corretamente as estruturas de dados e APIs da linguagem.

Em linguagems que possuem *garbage collector* é essencial se atentar para *memory leaks* em atributos estáticos, tal como mapas que nunca tem seus itens removidos.

Outro problema é a leitura de muitos dados em memória sem necessidade. Algumas pessoas fazem leitura de banco de dados e arquivo todo em memória para depois processar as informações, sendo que você poderia fazer isso registro a registro ou linha a linha.

### Desempenho

O desempenho também pode ser muito afetado pela forma como um sistema é implementado.

Isso pode começar na forma como o banco de dados é modelado, na forma como o sistema lê e grava dados e nos algoritmos implementados.

A leitura e gravação em banco de dados deve ser pensada com cuidado, evitando `select *` e fazer *updates* em massa quando possível ao invés de atualizar registros um a um.

Para arquivos é interessante usar *streams* para leitura e gravação, ao contrário da prática comum de carregar tudo sempre para uma String em memória.

## Desempenho, memória e complexidade

Diminuir a complexidade de um programa pode ajudar a diminuir o uso de memória e melhorar o desempenho.

A quantidade de loops e comparações pode ser reduzida utilizando estruturas de dados adequadas. Por exemplo, em muitas situações podemos usar um mapa baseado em *hash*para recuperar elementos baseados em uma chave ao invés de usar `indexOf` em listas e vetores. No melhor caso, um mapa permite a recuperação de um item sem iterações, em um único passo, enquanto nas listas poderá ser necessário varrer todos os elementos para encontrar um objeto lá dentro.

Pode-se também economizar memória ao evitar o uso de variáveis e estruturas de dados desnecessárias. Ou ainda evitar a geração de valores em memória desnecessariamente, usando `StringBuffer`s ou equivalentes ao invés de concatenação de Strings, por exemplo.

## Código legível e otimizações

Em geral, um programador tenta escrever código simples e legível, afinal a manutenção é um fator muito importante na maioria dos sistemas.

Porém, em casos específicos, é possível que ele "quebre" certas regras por priorizar algum outro quesito de qualidade: desempenho, disponibilidade, uso eficiente de memória ou algum outro recurso.

Um exemplo disso é em sistemas de "tempo real", onde é necessário extrair o máximo de desempenho ao custo de ter um código bem difícil de ler.

Ou ainda quando se decide usar comunicação socket em UDP com um protocolo proprietário ao invés de um web service REST devido ao volume de dados.

## Considerações

Enfim, tudo isso foi para dizer que, sim, código complexo geralmente prejudica o desempenho e o uso de memória.

Tentei nos tópicos acima considerar alguns pontos bastante genéricos, mas que são relevantes para a discussão.

Comment: cara excelente explicação, a principio gostaria de saber somente se a complexidade do código poderia afetar no desempenho e uso de memoria ram do servidor, você foi alem disso e deu uma resposta excelente. Venho utilizando a pratica de código limpo, reduzindo sempre a complexidade de um ano pra cá, mas tenho este projeto já a 3 anos, que foi criado quando não conhecia a respeito de complexidade de código. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

com certeza!
um algoritmo do tipo:

```
for (i, i<n, i++){
   for (j, j<n, j++){
      for (k, k<n, k++){
          exec algo;
      }
      exec algo;
   }
   exec algo;
}
```

tera uma complexidade n^3

Enquanto um algoritmo do mesmo tipo, so que recursivo, tera uma complexidade 3*n

A intenção é sempre otimizar o código para que a máquina sofra o menos possível

Answer (score 2):

Loop dentro do outro pode ser um problema, depende muito do que você fez e como fez! Tente detalhar um pouco melhor. Poste pequenas partes "importantes" do código para uma melhor análise da comunidade.

O que o @Marcelo Bonifazio disse está parcialmente correto, porém depende da situação, recursividade não compete com inline.

Comment: Entendi @Trplz0, porem minha dúvida era um tanto ampla, como é uma aplicação antiga e comparando com minhas aplicações recentes sei que ela o nivel de código é bem complexo, muitos métodos fazendo muitas coisas, não era simples. Hoje tenho outra visão e como essa aplicação esta ocupando uma memoria ram um tanto excessiva no servidor, estou considerando reescrever parte do código dela. Mas antes de fazer isso queria saber se isso poderia ser um dos principais motivos dela utilizar tanta memoria ram.

Comment: Um jeito fácil de verificar o consumo de RAM é analisar cada variável que você cria, pois elas que consomem a RAM. Se você bater o olho no código e notar que você duplica variáveis, instancia objetos sem necessidade isso vai consumir uma quantidade de RAM para aquele request e quando você multiplicar pelas múltiplas requisições você tem o consumo do servidor, outro ponto é analisar os métodos criados e tentar diminuir o impacto deles. Isso vem de uma manutenção no código por longo período. Testes unitários é a melhor ferramenta para analise desses métodos! vou continuar no próximo comentário..

Comment: Procure analisar também o retorno de dados do banco e ordem desses retornos com o input do usuário. Vejo muito isso, retornar alguns dados para uso posterior a validação do usuário mas se a validação falhar você alerta o usuário e não faz o uso desses dados previamente carregados, ou seja, apenas foi até o banco, consumiu memória com os dados pra nada.

Se você utilizou algum framework para desenvolver, você deve fazer um teste dele limpo, apenas um hello world e ver o consumo. Com base nisso você vai ter a certeza de que é o seu código que está custando X e o framework custa Y.